# Get property name and type by pass it directly

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, properties

I asked similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205427/get-the-instance-name-of-the-object-no-the-object-type-name-in-c-sharp-4-0) And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205026/pass-property-to-the-method-in-c-sharp)

This is a sample Type:

```
    public class Product {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }

}
```

And I have a Generic class that needs properties to generate some HTML codes:

```
public class Generator<T> {

    public T MainType { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedProperties { get; set; }

    public string Generate() {

        Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> props;
        props = typeof(T)
                .GetProperties()
                .ToDictionary<PropertyInfo, string>(prop => prop.Name);

        Type propType = null;
        string propName = "";
        foreach(string item in SelectedProperties) {
            if(props.Keys.Contains(item)) {
                propType = props[item].PropertyType;
                propName = item;

                // Generate Html by propName & propType
            }
        }
```

And I use this types as following:

```
Product pr = new Product();
Generator<Product> GT = new Generator<Product>();
GT.MainType = pr;
GT.SelectedProperties = new List<string> { "Title", "IsAllowed" };

GT.Generate();
```

So I think this process should be more easy as is but I don't know how implement it, I think to pass properties to the generator more simple, something like the followings Pseudo-code:

```
GT.SelectedProperties.Add(pr.Title);
GT.SelectedProperties.Add(pr.IsAllowed);
```

I don't know is this possible or not, I need just two things 1-PropertyName like: `IsAllowed` 2- property type like : `bool`. Maybe don't need to pass `MainType` I use it to get property types so if I can handle like the above don't need it any more.

What is your suggestion to implement something like this?

Is there any better way to do this?

**Update**

As `ArsenMkrt` said I found can use `MemberExpression` but I can't get Property Type, I see the property type in debugging see the picture:

[image]

So how can I get property type?

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224119/get-property-type-by-memberexpression).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [expression tree](http://neutrongenious.wordpress.com/2009/05/28/how-to-get-property-name-using-expression-tree/), than your code will look like this

```
GT.SelectedProperties.Add(p=>p.Title);
GT.SelectedProperties.Add(p=>p.IsAllowed);
```

You will need to create custom collection class derived from List for SelectedProperties and create add method like this

```
   //where T is the type of your class
   public string Add<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
   {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (body == null) 
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");
        //Call List Add method with property name
        Add(body.Member.Name);
   }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for answer, that's really helpful, but I can't get `PropertyType`, I see the property type in debugging but I don't know how get it, as I update question, do you know how get it?

Comment: @Saeid, I believe ((PropertyInfo)body.Member).PropertyType will return type you are looking for